# Using two different functions to change variable in main and print

Tags: c

So I have to create two functions. In the int main, the program asks to input an x and y value. On the first function, it adds 1 to the x and y value. And on the next function, it prints out the result from that function. And now my problem is that the 2nd function doesn't print out the output from the first function, I do not know what I'm doing wrong, here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plusone(int *x,int *y);
void printresult(int *x, int *y);

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("enter x variable: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("enter y variable: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    plusone(&x,&y);

    printf ("%d and %d\n\n",x,y);
    printresult(&x,&y);
}

void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    return *x+1;
}

void printresult(int *x,int *y)
{
    printf("the result is: x:%d y:%d",*x,*y);
}
```

so when I run that program, enter 1 for x and 2 for y, the output is still 1 and 2, but it's supposed to be 2 for x and 2 for y after the plusone function, can I ask what's wrong with my code? Sorry for my english but I hope I explained it well, I am new to C programming

Comment: Why are you passing the arguments as pointers?

Comment: `plustone` should be `*x=*x+1;` without `return *x+1;`

Comment: Because she wants to change their contents -- not that she is trying to, but still...

Comment: Is there a better way to go about it? I tried not setting them as pointers but it didn't register the new values in after the first function?

Answer (score 3):

A better answer is that the plusone function is not applying any side-effect on the *x parameter.  Here is a plusone function that has a side-effect (actually two--one on each variable passed in):

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    *x = *x+1;
    *y = *y+1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer to `plusone` - that's a good start. However, you are not using that pointer to update the value passed in:

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    *x = *x+1;
}
```

or better

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    (*x)++;
}
```

Now you assign a new value to whatever `x` is pointing, that is, to the variable `x` of `main`.

Note: Since you were returning a value from a function declared `void`, the compiler should have given you a warning.

Note: although passing by pointer to `plusone` is necessary, you can pass by value to `printresult`, because the function does not need to change values of the local variables in `main` that you pass to it.

Comment: thank you very much, this fixed my problem!! I used *x+=1 and it's working like it should!!

Answer (score 1):

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    return *x+1;
}
```

should be

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    (*x)++; //or *x+=1; which is the short for *x=*x+1;
}
```

You cannot return an `int` for a function that does not return anything (`void`).But here,I don't think you were attempting to return a variable.You wanted the variable `x` to be incremented once.So just do that in your program just like I've done above.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return from `plusone`, this is the right solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plusone(int *x, int *y);
void printresult(int x, int y);

int /* main() returns int */ main()
{
    int x, y;

    printf("enter x variable: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("enter y variable: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    plusone(&x, &y);
    printresult(x, y);

    return 0; // main sholud return `int' as you see from it's definition.
}

void
plusone(int *x, int *y)
{
    *x += 1;
    *y += 1;
}

void printresult(int x, int y)
{
    printf("the result is:\n\tx: %d\n\ty: %d\n", x, y);
}
```

You said,

> it adds 1 to the x and y value_

in your `plusone` function you was passing `int *y` but never doing anything with it, and `int *x` but not updating it's value.

Comment: You really deleted your own answer after reading others answers and rewrited the code? One ban wasn't enough for you?

Comment: No, after re-reading the question. Im sorry if I answered too fast, but you can see that I have gained reputation since the ban.

Comment: @Quest except for the most upvoted answer: _the one that I think should be picked actually (@MichelTiemann's answer)_, no one addressed the problem, he wanted to add one to `x` and `y` not just `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`plusone` is trying to return an `int` what it's return type is void.  And it isn't even trying to change anything (no assignment statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to manipulate the x and y variables directly, like I think you are, you need to do something like

```
*x += 1;
*y += 1;
```

in that function

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution.

```
void plusone(int *x,int *y)
{
    *x += 1;
}
```

I think your original source will make compile error due to return int in void function